# redshift User Defined Lambda Function returns error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I followed all the steps mentioned in this official tutorial to create a redshift lambda function.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/accessing-external-components-using-amazon-redshift-lambda-udfs/

I am able to use my own code instead of the code provided in that example.
It works as expected.

```
# select 123456 as input_number, mycircle('123456');
 input_number |      mycircle
--------------+--------------------
 123456 |  Mumbai 
(1 row)
```

But the same function does not work when used in a table like this...

```
# select input_number, mycircle(input_number) from mytable  limit 1;
ERROR:  Invalid Lambda Response
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid Lambda Response
  code:      8001
  context:   Missing rows in lambda response
  query:     2983079
  location:  exfunc_data.cpp:288
  process:   query0_121_2983079 [pid=29202]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

It seems the UDF does not work like any other python UDF's those are already supported by redshift.
How do I use my lambda function as user defined function in this query?

---

Update:

My function is written in such a way that it will work only if I create a new table with only 1 row.

```
# create table todel as select * from  mytable  limit 1;
```

and then run the UDF on the newly created table, it works:

```
#  select input_number, mycircle(input_number) from todel;
```

This is not expected and my other python UDF work correctly as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sure to return the right number of output rows which matches your input rows. Remember the function does not expect just one input row, but instead processes in "batches".